# SplPriorityQueue::next() is removing the item

Tags: php, iterator, spl

I would like to know how could I iterate a SplHeap or SplPriorityQueue more than once.

next() method removes the last item, so the second foreach (or for) is not getting any result.

Example:

```
<?php
class Teste extends SplPriorityQueue {}

$teste = new Teste();
$teste->insert( 'A', 1 );
$teste->insert( 'B', 3 );
$teste->insert( 'D', 5 );
$teste->insert( 'C', 2 );
$teste->insert( 'A', 4 );

echo '<pre>';

var_dump( $teste->count() );

echo '<br>';

foreach( $teste as $t )
    var_dump( $t );

echo '<br>';

var_dump( $teste->count() );
```

Returns:

```
int(5)

string(1) "D"
string(1) "A"
string(1) "B"
string(1) "C"
string(1) "A"

int(0) <--- I need this to still be 5
```

I need to insert items based on a compare() method, like this: http://php.net/manual/en/splheap.compare.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like to know how could I iterate a SplHeap or SplPriorityQueue more than once.

The short answer is, you don't iterate more than once *for an individual instance of the class*.

The slightly longer answer is to instead use multiple identical instances when iterating. This can be easily achieved by iterating over a `clone` of the heap/pqueue.

**Quicky example**

```
<?php

$queue = new SplPriorityQueue();
$queue ->insert('A', 30);
$queue ->insert('C', 10);
$queue ->insert('B', 20);

var_dump(count($queue));
foreach (clone $queue as $item) {
    var_dump($item);
}
var_dump(count($queue));
foreach (clone $queue as $item) {
    var_dump($item);
}
var_dump(count($queue));
```

The above outputs:

```
int(3)
string(1) "A"
string(1) "B"
string(1) "C"
int(3)
string(1) "A"
string(1) "B"
string(1) "C"
int(3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what if I wanted to use SplObjectStorage with automatically sorted objects, like SplHeap does with compare() method?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you're asking, but you should be able to do the above without any problems.